Action (of a graded monoid) required
Reference request: Did the construction below appear anywhere before? Any mentions of it or especially any links to something commonly known would be really helpful. I feel that it might be related to operads, but I can not figure out the details. See also the question below.
Construction: Everything below can be easily adapted to rings/algebras, but we describe it for monoids. Let $M=\bigsqcup\limits_{p\geq 0} M_p$ be a graded monoid ($M_p$ are sets). Let $N$ be another graded monoid $N=\bigsqcup\limits_{p\geq 0}N_p$. Then $\bigsqcup\limits_{p\geq 0} M_p\times N_p$ is a graded monoid again and suppose we have a homomorphism of graded monoids
\begin{equation}
\varphi:\bigsqcup\limits_{p\geq 0} M_p\times N_p\longrightarrow \bigsqcup\limits_{p\geq 0} N_p
\end{equation}
Explicitly this means that for any $p\geq 0$ we have a map $\varphi_p:M_p\times N_p\longrightarrow N_p$, which satisfies the following property
$$
\varphi_{p_1+p_2}(m_1m_2,n_1n_2)=\varphi_{p_1}(m_1,n_1)\varphi_{p_2}(m_2,n_2),
$$
for $m_1\in M_{p_1}$, $n_1\in N_{p_1}$, $m_2\in M_{p_2}$, and $n_2\in N_{p_2}$, where on the left hand-side $m_1m_2$ and $n_1n_2$ mean products of elements in the corresponding monoids as well as on the right hand-side we have a product of two $\varphi$'s which is understood as the product of elements of $N$.
Question: It is very desirable to treat this $\varphi$ as an action of something related to $M$ on something related to $N$. In the example below this is almost done, except the fact that there each graded component $\varphi_p$ is an action map, and I wish to recast this in terms of $M$ and $N$ themselves, but not their graded components. In the best-case scenario, I want to find a (known) action-like structure whose definition is exactly given by the construction above. It might sound like ''a graded monoid $M$ acts on a graded monoid $N$ in the sense of something, if there is a homomorphism $\varphi$ ...''.
Example: Take $M_p=S(p)$ the symmetric group and $N_p=V^{\otimes p}$ the $p$-th tensor power of a vector space $V$. Then $M$ is a monoid with respect to “concatenation” of permutations $S(p)\times S(q)\longrightarrow S(p+q)$, $(\sigma,\tau)\mapsto \sigma\times\tau$, where $\sigma\times\tau$ permutes the first $p$ elements as $\sigma$ and the last $q$ elements as $\tau$. And $N$ is a monoid with respect to the tensor product. Then each $\varphi_p$ is just the usual action of the symmetric group by permutations of tensors
$$
(\sigma,v_1\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_p)\mapsto (v_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}\otimes\dotsb\otimes v_{\sigma^{-1}(p)})
$$
for $\sigma\in S(p)$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_p\in V$.
Cross-posted at MathStackExchange

Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4979819/weird-construction-with-graded-monoids-rings-algebras
